# Send message every second to clients using signalR with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to send some kind of timer to server to all connected clients.
I was able to do this on button click. But what I really need is to send this timer every second automatically.

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Signalr Chat Messenger</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

            IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message  + '</li>');
            };

            IWannaChat.client.addTest = function (timer) {
                $('#lblTimer').text(timer);
            };

            $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
                IWannaChat.server.send($('#txtMessage').val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();

        });
    </script>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtMessage" />
        <input type="button" id="SendMessage" value="broadcast" /><asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" Text="timer"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<ul id="listMessages">
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my **HUB**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System.Threading;

namespace SignalRChat
{
    [HubName("myChatHub")]
    public class LetsChat : Hub
    {
        DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.Now;
        string dateTime1 = "11.04.2016 15:49:00";   




        public void send(string message)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var diffInSeconds = (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime1) - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;

            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
            Clients.All.addTest(diffInSeconds.ToString());
            //Clients.All.addTest(dateTime1.ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `System.Timers.Timer` to do that:

```
public class LetsChat : Hub
{
    private static readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    static LetsChat()
    {
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    static void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<LetsChat>();

        var diffInSeconds = (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime1) - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;

       hub.Clients.All.addMessage("Message");
       hub.Clients.All.addTest(diffInSeconds.ToString());
    }

    public void send(string message)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var diffInSeconds = (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime1) - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;

        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        Clients.All.addTest(diffInSeconds.ToString());
        //Clients.All.addTest(dateTime1.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. tried your code but it's not working. maybe you forgot something?

Comment: to be more clear I get the following error on the line: send("Message");
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: updated the answer. you will need to get the hub inside elapsed method as it is static.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is working partially. I still get the same error on the static void TimerElapsed. If I comment these 2 lines 
//var diffInSeconds = (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime1) - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;
//hub.Clients.All.addTest(diffInSeconds.ToString()); it is working... I get only the string Message being duplicated... I need the secconds

Comment: you can make datetime1 and datetime2 static.

Comment: Does this run per user-instance? So if I have a 100 users they would each have their own instance of this timer? Or does it execute once and then broadcast to all users?

Comment: @zerohero it is the later case.